# MySQL - How to handle historical data?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I am new to the world of database design, but have been building a fairly complex (to me) system for an application I developed for my work.

I'll use examples here, as posting my actual database structure would be too much.

Suppose I have a table of `[products]` for sale and another table to record all the individual `[sales]`.

The `[sales]` table contains a foreign key referencing the `id` from the `[products]` table.  However, as time goes on, that `product` may no longer be available and needs to be deleted from the `[products]` table altogether.

Obviously, with a FK pointing to that `product` from the `[sales]` table, I can either restrict deleting of the `product` (noaction), delete the `sale` record (cascade), or set the `product` to null (setnull). None of those options is appropriate, as we would still need to know what `product` was sold in that `sale`.

**A Couple Solutions I Thought Of**

1. Instead of deleting the `product` from the `[products]` table, I could
   flag it as "inactive" or "unavailable" instead.
2. Insert a duplicate record of the `product` into a separate "historical" table and update the `[sales]` table's FK to point there instead. Then delete the original record from the `[products]` table.
3. Remove the foreign key altogether and trust my application to handle the link correctly on its own (ie: instead of a FK pointing to the `product_id`, my `[sales]` table could instead use a `VARCHAR` for the `product_name`, requiring a text match to retrieve the additional `product` details). ****Bad idea****

What is one way this could be implemented?

Comment: There are a lot of questions about this. The general topic is "historical" & "temporal" data/DBs/DBMSs. However "the standard for implementing this" is not a good SO question. And please ask one question per question. See [ask] & [help] links.

Comment: In my experience the `inactive` column approach works but will regurgitate here and there in unexpected places where queries don't utilize the column and it's easy to forget to include it in queries. I prefer having a dedicated table for "deleted" history then use JOINS where something needs to reference it thus preventing it from popping-up in unexpected places in the future to behave more like something deleted. So, I'd be voting for `#2` from the solutions you thought of.

Comment: I edited my question to make it just one question and answerable, @philipxy. Thank you. I was also unsure how to best search for this topic so thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: @Ultimater Another thing I forgot to mention is that the product could become available again in the future, so that would require removing from the "historical" table, adding back to the original, and then updating the sale record, yes?

Comment: As per knowledge , deleting data [ which holds historical imp @ some point of time] from table is a very bad idea. Using flags to mark a product active/inactive is best options and will help u to reuse those products in future if needed. Your queries can use the flag to generate report where you only want active products sales. I would suggest go for option 1.

Comment: @Zephyr That's fine. You can always add the product back in under the same primary key is was previously using if you need an `undelete` functionality. Simply delete it from the history table afterwards. If it gets deleted again, just keep on using the same primary key to refer to the same data in both tables. `#1` is definitely easier to implement but if you can't risk  regurgitation, `#2` will set your mind at ease and make future queries easier.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't yet earned comment everywhere rights so here i come posting on the answer side,
I am up for the `inactive` tag as deleting information especially information referenced elsewhere can be tragic.
If you want to make it more interesting, here's how:
What if a product can be inactive and then active again and you want to track information specific to these periods? 
or what if the product's price keeps on changing (and it's listed on the product table) but you want to track historical sales based on the prices that were at that time?

You would essentially have to create a star setting where you version your products with every new significant change and give them change_keys.
This way, you can go back and reference all different instances of your product.